# Should I use MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

So we have a system, this system writes huge amounts of data to a logging DB. This data is only read when something goes wrong, the rest of the time it's sat their just in case.

This data is currently stored in a SQL Server DB in the following structure:

- Data written to a "*write*" DB
- Periodically this is archived off into a seperate DB
- Data is kept for 7 days
- currently upto 100Gb of data written into SQL everyday
- Data is simple, no joins, etc. just flat data linked by a foreign key

So I'm thinking would this be more efficently stored in a NoSQL system, like [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/)

As far as I can see, from reading several articles([here](http://www.10gen.com/nosql) and [here](http://www.mongodb.org/about/introduction/) for example), this has the following advantages

- Horizontal scaling
- <strike>Fast writing</strike>
- Fits unstructured nature of the data
- not concerned with read performance, just write performance and space

**So my question(s) are predominately does this fit do we think?**

**Particuarly**

1. Does Mongo take more or less space on the disk for the comparative SQL equivalent?
2. Are deletes more or less efficient than SQL?
3. With the horizontal scaling does this use large amounts of network traffic?

Comment: 1. Yes it can take more, 2. About the same, 3. only if you have a bad shard key, replication can use a fair amount but that is replication, if you don't want durability then minus that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience Mongo does ok with writes, but it's not spectacular. At a previous job, our production instance struggled quite a bit more with writes than reads.

Mongo is *very* aggressive with allocating files on disk. Read this: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/#why-are-the-files-in-my-data-directory-larger-than-the-data-in-my-database

Eventually Mongo tries to grab 2GB at a time even if your database is empty.

From my experience I found deletes to be pretty efficient. No real complaints, but then again we weren't deleting a lot of data.

The horizontal scaling from my experience was pretty chatty, but it has to be to replicate data. The thing to read about is the difference between using a replica set or using sharding. The replication model/network activity is pretty different between the two.

We used Mongo mostly for efficient reads and it did really well with that.

Comment: Thats good to know. I was under the impression that the writes were faster, the pre-allocation of space could be a deal killer too. Thanks!

Comment: "Eventually Mongo tries to grab 2GB at a time even if your database is empty." really? It should only allocate a 2GB extent when it feels it needs to "Eventually Mongo tries to grab 2GB at a time even if your database is empty." replication is not sharding, do you mean balancing? If so you may have had a bad shard key.

Comment: That has been my experience. From the link: "In the data directory, MongoDB preallocates data files to a particular size, in part to prevent file system fragmentation. MongoDB names the first data file <databasename>.0, the next <databasename>.1, etc. The first file mongod allocates is 64 megabytes, the next 128 megabytes, and so on, up to 2 gigabytes, at which point all subsequent files are 2 gigabytes. The data files include files with allocated space but that hold no data. mongod may allocate a 1 gigabyte data file that may be 90% empty.

Comment: @ryan1234 Yes it can allocate an extent that is nearly empty to 2GB but it can't allocate 2GB to an empty database. The allocation on collection level is why you shouldn't try and scale vertically, if you scale horizontally you will actually find MongoDB, as you quote, incrementally increases the size dependant upon rules for judging the traffic of writes.

Comment: Good note. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

If you're storing logging data, why not use Logstash? Logstash uses Elasticsearch as storage and both writes and queries are very fast and it also scales well. Couple Logstash with http://kibana.org/ and you've got yourself your own personal log analysis and querying dashboard.

MongoDB is not a bad choice either. Some really good logging and exception apps like Errbit use MongoDB as the backend.

When using mongodb for vigorous logging it helps to send data from ur application to a middleware on the udp port which in turn writes to mongo. That way there is almost 0 wait for writes to happen. The advantage is that while the udp port receives the data and lets your app resume, the middleware can do safe writes to mongo, thus making sure log integrity is maintained.

Comment: Isn't UDP without quality control which means you can still lose a data and more specifically a write on it? If you want something like that why don't you just use MongoDB with write concern of `0`? It will have the same chance of loss from the application end

Comment: Yes. But it is much faster and therefore best for fast logging and message sending. Sending through a UDP app running on the sam machine, chances of failure are really low.

Comment: Yeah but that's also the case about write concern `0`, it is much faster but as some say, "It is like writing to `/dev/null`", chances of losing data with write concern `0` on same machine are nill but that isn't enough for people